# Autodesk Maya symbol lookup error on start after installing AMD proprietary driver on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, amd-graphics, 3d, amdgpu

I've installed Maya 2018 on Ubuntu 18.04 and tested it with the amdgpu driver (open source) and it launched without problems, but some components were not working with the open source driver so I tried amd gpu pro 18.20 (amd closed-source driver). I ran

```
./amdgpu-pro-install
```

but since then Maya won't work and gives this warning message:

```
./maya.bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/autodesk/maya2018/bin/..
/lib/libOGSDeviceOGL4-16.so: undefined symbol: EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init
```

My card is hd7770 and it's supported by the amd closed driver, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I was just debugging the same issue. This happens for the following reason. Most of the maya installation guides on ubuntu involve creating a symbolic link of libssl.so inside the maya installation (naming it libssl.so.10) so maya can load the ssl library. (since it looking for this specific name) However, ubuntu 18 has both libssl1.0 and libssl1.1 installed. 1.1 is missing the EVP_CYPHER_CTX_init symbol, (amongst some other ones) so you have to create a symlink pointing to libssl.so.1.0.0 instead of libssl.so.

Ie, run this command:

```
 sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/autodesk/maya2018/lib/libssl.so.10
```

Comment: Thanks!  This solution worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 as well, but I had to install libssl1.0.0:  `sudo apt-get install -y libssl1.0.0`