# I can't run maya 2017 on ubuntu 18.04.1 (undefined symbol: EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init)

Tags: software-installation, openssl

When I try to run Maya I get:

```
gravit@Gravit-PC:~$ sudo /usr/autodesk/maya2017/bin/maya.bin

Initialized VP2.0 renderer {
 Version : 2016.3.18.11. Feature Level 5.
 Adapter : GeForce GT 1030/PCIe/SSE2
 Vendor ID: 4318. Device ID : 
 Driver : 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.87.
 API : OpenGL V.4.6.
 Max texture size : 16384 * 16384.
 Max tex coords : 32
 Shader versions supported (Vertex: 5, Geometry: 5, Pixel 5).
 Shader compiler profile : (Best card profile)
 Active stereo support available : 0
 GPU Memory Limit : 2048 MB.
 CPU Memory Limit: 7524.27 MB.
/usr/autodesk/maya2017/bin/maya.bin: symbol lookup error: 
/usr/autodesk/maya2017/bin/../lib/libOGSDeviceOGL4-16.so: undefined symbol: 
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init
```

I used this instruction https://linuxhint.com/install_autodesk_maya_ubuntu_1804/

When I try solution from here: [Autodesk Maya symbol lookup error on start after installing AMD proprietary driver on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061236/autodesk-maya-symbol-lookup-error-on-start-after-installing-amd-proprietary-driv)

I get this:

gravit@Gravit-PC:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/autodesk/maya2017/lib/libssl.so.10
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/autodesk/maya2017/lib/libssl.so.10': File exists

Comment: No, it's not. When I try that solution I get this:
gravit@Gravit-PC:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/autodesk/maya2017/lib/libssl.so.10
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/autodesk/maya2017/lib/libssl.so.10': File exists

Comment: You should read error messages (`File exists`). You need to remove the link to the library that was created by maya before creating a new one. Run `sudo rm /usr/autodesk/maya2017/lib/libssl.so.10`. You can do that, because it's just a link to a library, not the libray itself. Then again run `sudo ln -s ...`

Comment: Yes. You were right. Thank you! everything works now!

Comment: :-) Glad that I could help.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day @RoVo