# EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init Maya 2019 Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: software-installation, 19.04

After trying to install Maya 2019 on Ubuntu 19.04 with this method: [How to Install Autodesk Maya 2019 on Ubuntu 19.04 using NVIDIA GPU – Linux Hint](https://linuxhint.com/install_autodesk_maya2019_ubuntu/)

When I launch Maya, the app stop at the start frame. It gave me this type of error:

```
/usr/autodesk/maya2019/bin/maya.bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/autodesk/maya2019/bin/../lib/libOGSDeviceOGL4-16.so: undefined symbol: EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init
```

I tried different [solution provided on this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061236/autodesk-maya-symbol-lookup-error-on-start-after-installing-amd-proprietary-driv) for earlier versions, and look at the [post on autodesk forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-forum/failed-to-initialize-graphics-device-maya-2019-on-linux-mint/m-p/8632405#M69813) too but it failed. I couldn't launch the software.

How can I run this successfully?

Comment: Hmm, am not using Maya and 19.04, but from your description, Maya needs openssl 1.0, however Ubuntu 19.04 only provides openssl 1.1+(18.04 and 18.10 have openssl1.0 package). Maybe you can start from installing openssl 1.0, then retry the first solution you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your answer,

I finally emailed the owner of the post on linux hint & he told me to remove the libssl.so.10 like as advised by a member of the Autdsk staff on their forum :

[Autdsk forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/installation-licensing/can-t-run-maya-2017-on-ubuntu-18-04-1/td-p/8243374)

I tried (changing maya2017 for 2019 obviously), nothing happened. Same error than before.

So I decided to get rid of the "libOGSDeviceOGL4-16.so" cause maybe it was part of the solution. And...

Maya start !

But now there's a problem in the color system/graphic device (Even if rendering is ok).

```
VP2 Error : Failed to initialize graphics device.
Error: The GPU adaptor of the transform to finalize is null
Error: Failed to apply color management settings on file open: Failed to finalize the color transform..
Error: The GPU adaptor of the transform to finalize is null
Error: Failed to finalize the color transform.
Unable to execute igInitialize.mel.Unable to execute xgen.mel.
API error detected in /local/S/Maya_2019_DI/src/Maya/src/Type/pluginMain.cpp at line 163
: (kFailure): Unexpected Internal Failure

API error detected in plugins/mtoa/extension/ExtensionsManager.cpp at line 655
: (kFailure): Unexpected Internal Failure

API error detected in plugins/mtoa/extension/ExtensionsManager.cpp at line 655
: (kFailure): Unexpected Internal Failure
```

At least I can use the software...I'm going to add libssl.so.10 in the lib folder to see if it changes something else...

Comment: Program seems to work for me here, without libssl.so.10 and libOGSDeviceOGC4-16.so but without arnold viewport...viewport 2.0 only... It's  nearly solutionized...but nearly only... :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the RPM file that provides libssl.so.10:
   https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/32/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/c/compat-openssl10-1.0.2o-9.fc32.x86_64.rpm
2. Use alien to convert it to a DEB file, and install it
3. ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/libcrypto.so.10
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10
   ```
4. Done

Comment: *"Use alien to convert it to a DEB file"* -- how exactly do you do this?  Can you elaborate?  Please use the editing tools to format commands and terminal output in `monospace` font so we can tell them apart from the surrounding text.

Answer (score 0):

Downloads the RPM file that provides libssl.so.10, then use alien tool to convert it to a .deb file and install it. Then do `ln -s file_A file_B`.

Just do it step by step:

```
wget https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/32/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/c/compat-openssl10-1.0.2o-9.fc32.x86_64.rpm
sudo apt install -y alien elfutils
sudo alien -cv *.rpm
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/libcrypto.so.10
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10
```